# How to config Angular to bundle SCSS files from library?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular8

How to config Angular to bundle some SCSS files from library?

I have created a library using this [instruction.](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

This libary has a lot of ts files with **.scss** files.

How to configure **angular.json** to bundle all these **.scss** files from library and include it in production (ng serve)?

I know `angular.json` allows to configure Angular project and library in section: `{projects: []}`.

Comment: In this library, is the SCSS being referenced by components via `styleUrls` or similar? As long as the components are using the SCSS specifically, it will be bundled with the components/modules exported from the library. Please share code on how SCSS is used/linked/reference in the library.

Comment: Library is it not angular application it is plain typescript files .ts that generate DOM

Comment: In angular.json under architect -> build & serve, just add the path to the scss files under the 'styles' array. Unless it's an actual library, which would be different and you might need to add more clarity to your question because as it sits it's difficult to give a good answer.

Comment: Path to library? Libary is noy located in src. it is outside in projects directory

Answer (score 1):

You can import those third parties' SCSS libraries in your global SCSS file. Let's assume you want to import the SCSS file from a library called dummy, and library dummy looks like this inside `node_modules` directory

```
node_modules/
|
|__dummy
        |
        |__styles
                |
                |__dummy.scss`
```

Then you can import `dummy.scss` in your `style.scss` like this

`@import '~dummy/styles/dummy.scss';`

Basically, the tilde `~` is like an alias to `node_modules` directory

Comment: I have own library not node_modules.  So, files ts from this library use CSS properties from SCSS in code. How to bundle this?

Comment: Just import them in your SCSS files using the above syntax, of course, give it the path to your SCSS files `@import 'path/to/imported/scss/file';` without the tilde `~`